# c# text compare rate find

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two texts and I want to compare them and find their similarity ratios. For example, the similarity rate of the words "hasan" and "hasna" is 95%. The only solution I can think of about this is to convert the texts to char arrays and make comparisons, but it seemed unreasonable. Does anyone have a useful function or a workaround? Do not recommend Contains.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe in detail what you want? Do you want to search "hasan" in a text and then also find "hasna"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare strings you have to compare all the characters. So I'm not sure why you think it is unreasonable to make comparisons.

Have a look at. There are many string similarity metrics. As you give 95% you probably have a specific one in mind.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20computer%20science,and%20in%20fuzzy%20string%20searching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20computer%20science,and%20in%20fuzzy%20string%20searching).

I'm sure you'll find plenty of implementations if you don't want to code it yourself.